# Tried a RAM upgrade on a slow laptop, but it made things worse

Tags: laptop, memory, performance, upgrade

Here’s a little story.

My dad got me a basic laptop when I started college back in 2018 (‘twas an [HP 14-cf0004ne](https://support.hp.com/emea_middle_east-en/document/c06073756); 4GB RAM, i3-7th gen), from a local computer store.
It was super slow from day-1 (booting, opening files, browsing internet), which was annoying, but at least I was able to get (some) work done on the thing.

As I grew more computer-literate over time, I came to the conclusion a RAM upgrade might help things.
So I ordered a *Crucial* 8GB DDR4 SODIMM card off of Amazon, and *replaced* the existing 4GB card with it today. I tried booting up the laptop… but it was *even* slower than before (basically inoperable).

After a spot of googling, I think I found the problem: Me being the semi-computer-literate genius that I am, ended up ordering wrong kind of card - **2400MT/s** (as per the Amazon description) instead of the designated **2133** (*MHz?*) mentioned on HP’s website for my model.

[image]

Here’s the interesting/frustrating part: The 4GB RAM card I pulled out of the laptop was a **2666**(*MHz?*) *Samsung* card.
[image]
I guess that ended up answering my 2 year-old question about why my (then) brand-new laptop was so slow; it had a 4GB **2600**(*MHz*) card from a different company installed instead of a 4GB-**2133** (*MHz*) card by HP (I assume HP makes their own cards).

*-End of Story-*

Questions based on above-mentioned sad, sad, story:

1. During my attempt to resolve the problem(s) by browsing online, I only came across RAM speeds/frequencies expressed in *MHz*. However the card I bought online was rated in **MT/s**.
   Am I right in assuming "MT/s" is equivalent to "MHz"?
2. Why did replacing the 4GB-2666 (MHz) RAM card that came with my laptop, with an 8GB-2400 MT/s RAM card cause my laptop to *slow down*? As stupid as this may sound: Shouldn't the new 2400 MT/s card run better than the 2666 (Mhz?) card, seeing as it's closer in speed/frequency to the HP-recommended 2133 (MHz?) card?

[Disclaimer: I didn't put the 8GB card in *with* the 4GB card; while the laptop does appear to have two RAM slots, I pulled out the 4GB card and *replaced* it with the 8GB one]

Comment: Have you considered reinstalling Windows.  Unless your system is running out of memory, and giving a warning to that effect, installing more memory won’t really solve performance problems you describe.

Comment: “Am I right in assuming "MT/s" is equivalent to "MHz"?” - No; They are absolutely not equivalent

Comment: @Ram Reinstalling Windows is beyond the realm of my (non-existent) expertise, so I haven't considered it. Now I haven't received any explicit memory-shortage warnings, but if it means anything... my laptop stutters and blacks-out on me whenever I open 5 or more tabs on Adobe Acrobat Reader (I use PDFs a lot), which is a pretty RAM-heavy application, if the Task Manager data is anything to go by...

Comment: “my laptop stutters and blacks-out” - What?

Comment: @Ram As in "it doesn't respond and the screen literally goes black". I always have to power-off and reboot after that.

Comment: That isn’t a low memory problem.   That’s a hardware problem that definitely shouldn’t be happening.

Comment: Could be a VRAM issue, especially if the GPU shares system RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here's an answer: I did some research, and MT/s is not the same as MHZ. MT/s measures the data transfer rate while MHZ is the clock speed. For example, if a card operates at 1200 MHZ, then it also operates at 2400 MT/s, since DDR performs two operations per cycle. Your second question is now invalid because the new 8GB-2400 MT/s RAM runs at 1200 MHZ, causing your computer to slow down. You may be thinking that since the new card has 2400 MT/s, which is around the recommended 2133 MHZ, it'll be fine, but remember that DDR performs two operations per cycle, so the 2133 MHZ cards run at 4266 MT/s. Hope this answers your questions! [Source](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/462465-mts-mhz/)

Comment: That seems to clear up the first question (my confusion with MT/s and MHz). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Chip speed - 2666Mz is faster than 2133Mz.  The amount of memory would only help if the caching were slow, which by observation of your laptop performance, it is not slow.  Or, system is caching little enough to have no discernible impact.  So, you stepped down from a 2666Mz to a 2133Mz chip - that's about a 20% drop - yikes.

On a seemingly unrelated note, but I found highly relevant and somewhat related to this, I got 32Gb of memory and it barely improved performance - perhaps made it worse.  This was using Windows 11 23H2.

I assumed correctly it was something the OS could help control, even if it was a 'hardware' issue. The system uses cache, which writes heavily to disk, most notably swapfile.sys and pagefile.sys.  These are disabled via sysdm.cpl --> Advanced --> Performance --> Settings --> Advanced --> 'Programs' --> For each drive (not disk) that Paging File Size is not 'None', click 'No paging file', --> Set.  You must acknowledge the warning, then repeat for all drives with paging not yet 'None'.  Once that is done,  REPEAT as above for 'Background Services' --> set No paging file for all drives, if not already set from previous step.  Click Apply. Click Ok.  Click OK --> you will be prompted to Restart, click 'Restart Now' if you want to see results right away.

Do not disable write-cache, which allows RAM to store data instead of writing immediately, which will reduce drive activity and improve performance.

Comment: Disabling the system page file is horrible advice. You talked about seeing no performance gain. Disabling your system page file is likely the reason that was the case. While the frequency delta performance is more significant with DDR4 than it was with DDR3 a less than 300 MHz difference between 2133Mz and 2666MHz wouldn’t result in a noticeable performance loss. The real reason for the performance loss for the author likely is unanswerable since it was over 5 years ago.

Comment: Yes, disabling write cache is a mistake - I removed it - thanks. Disabling system page improved things for me.  System page writes to disk which hurts performance, in my case.  Don't down vote just because you don't "like' the solution, it worked for me is the point.  You are dead wrong, 2166/2666 = .82 ---> an 18% reduction which is absolutely noticeable.

Comment: This isn’t about liking. Without a page file, you are actively wasting RAM. That’s because of the way memory reservations (commitments) work on Windows. Enable the page file or waste (considerable) amounts of RAM. Check it out in Task Manager: Compare the “In use“ figure and the “Committed” figure. I’m currently at 20 GiB and 30 GiB, respectively.

Comment: I am consuming 20Gb out of 32Gb of physical RAM - peak.  What do I need a page file for?  It is my INTENTION to consume RAM that is otherwise unused.  You said 'waste' RAM?  Really?  Having 12Gb unused because of system page file IS A WASTE.  Get your story straight and stop mis-informing people.

Comment: Because memory that is committed but unused by the application truly is unused. It cannot be used for cache either. It just sits there, empty. With a page file, these commitments can be backed by the page file, making space in RAM for cache or just more software. Unless all RAM is actually really in use, the page file is basically idle. Memory is only “paged out” when absolutely required.

Comment: By turning pagefile off, my disk activity went for 50% to near 0%, my memory usage went up by about 2 Gb, leaving about 10Gb uncommitted.  My memory does not page because it is not consumed.  My memory is much bigger than the page file, which always pages when enabled. No, the fix isn't to grow the page file to 30Gb!  I am offering a solution - you can 'warn' people all you want.  Mine is a practical solution.  Yours is no solution.